# Initialize a calendar in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, calendar, initialization

If I do this:

```
new Estimacao("Aarão","Affenpinscher","Abóbora",new GregorianCalendar(1999,7,26),0),
```

Everything works as as expected.
But if i do this:

```
new Estimacao("Aarão","Affenpinscher","Abóbora",new Calendar(1999,7,26),0),
```

It can be done. As far as I know. We have to initialize calendar like this:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1999);
date.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);
```

The thing I want to know is if it's possible to use `Calendar`, and achieve the same as `GregorianCalendar`, when creating and initializing the object `new Estimacao` as above.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Calendar is an Abstract class, so you can't create an instance of it.  When you call getInstance it actually returns a new GregorianCalendar instance.  So it is the same as your first example.

So I guess the question is, why do you want to call new Calendar instead of new GregorianCalendar?  If it is just so that you can hide the implementation you are using then I would either just do what you have already done to initialise a Calendar. Or create a single method that takes the same parameters and hides the calls to the Calendar class, e.g.

```
public Calendar getCalendar(int day, int month, int year) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    // We will have to increment the month field by 1

    date.set(Calendar.MONTH, month+1);

    // As the month indexing starts with 0

    date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    return date;
}
```

Comment: Calendar isn't abstract, it just has no public Constructors.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html  check out the API, I think you will find it is abstract

Comment: The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next week.

Comment: Indeed, in Java 7 it is. I'm looking at older Java docs. Looks to have been made abstract in Java 7.

Comment: Nope, it has always been abstract

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-1/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/index.html Here is Java 1.2 doc that shows it as Abstract

Comment: Okay then, I stand corrected. It looks like we came up with the same solution though.

Answer (score 0):

create your own custom class with appropriate constructor and use the java Calendar class in that to initialize the your own calendar class object

Answer (score -1):

`Calendar` has no public constructors, and provides the `Calendar.getInstance()` method as a means of constructing instances of the class. If you need to parameterize construction of a `Calendar` object, why not just write a helper method on the class?

```
new Estimacao("Aarão","Affenpinscher","Abóbora", this.getCalendar(1999,7,26),0);

/* ...elided...other code in here */

private Calendar getCalendar(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Check the API, Calendar is Abstract